# data.table merging in R

Tags: r, data.table

I'm using  data.table_1.9.4 and the merge function seems to not work as expected. What am I doing wrong over here?

```
a
  letter num_num
1: a   1
2: b   2
3: c   3
4: d    4
5: e    5
6: f   6
> b
 letter num_num
1: a   3
2: b   4
3: c   5
4: d   6
5: e    5
6: f   5
> merge(as.data.frame(a),as.data.frame(b),by='letter',all=TRUE)
letter num_num.x num_num.y

##....Works as expected

> merge(a,b,by='letter',all=TRUE)
Error in setcolorder(dt, c(setdiff(names(dt), end), end)) :
```

neworder is length 2 but x has 3 columns.

Comment: It does work for me. I am using `data.table_1.9.5` though I would assume it to work for 1.9.4.  It may be better to show the datasets using `dput` though

Comment: `> DT1 = data.table(x=c("b","b","b","a","a"),v=c(1,2,3,4,5))

> DT2 = data.table(x=c("b","b","b","a","a"),v=c(1,2,3,4,5))

> merge(DT1,DT2,by="x",all=TRUE)
Error in setcolorder(dt, c(setdiff(names(dt), end), end)) : 
neworder is length 2 but x has 3 columns.
`

Comment: Try `merge(DT1,DT2,by="x",allow.cartesian = T)`. The problem is that you are joining duplicates on duplicates and you don't have unique key

Comment: Still fails. I tried even without duplicates. 
`> DT1 = data.table(x=c("b","a"),v=c(1,2))
> DT2 = data.table(x=c("b","a"),v=c(3,4))
> merge(DT1,DT2,by="x",allow.cartesian = T)
Error in setcolorder(dt, c(setdiff(names(dt), end), end)) : 
  neworder is length 2 but x has 3 columns.
> merge(DT1,DT2,by="x")
Error in setcolorder(dt, c(setdiff(names(dt), end), end)) : 
  neworder is length 2 but x has 3 columns.
`

Comment: @PritishKakodkar  For me, it works `merge(DT1,DT2,by="x",allow.cartesian = T)
   x v.x v.y
1: a   2   4
2: b   1   3`

Comment: Ah, I had used options(datatable.old.bywithoutby=TRUE) for some migration and it seems to have caused the breakage. Thank you gentlemen.